# How to import correctly js library (gigraph), into react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import gitgrapqh into React, following their demo, but I got an error, apparently load for a fraction of second la later raise an error.

App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'gitgraph.js';
import 'gitgraph.js/build/gitgraph.css';

export default class Gitgraph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.$gitgraph = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    const gitgraph = new GitGraph({ canvas: this.$gitgraph.current });

    const master = gitgraph
      .branch("master")
      .commit()
      .commit();

    gitgraph
      .branch("dev")
      .commit()
      .commit()
      .merge(master);
  }

  render() {
    return <canvas ref={this.$gitgraph} />;
  }
}
```

But I got this error.

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
Line 13:  'GitGraph' is not defined  no-undef
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Someone can help me.

Comment: Have you tried using a named import? `import gitgraph from ‘gitgraph’;`

Comment: Importing a file without naming the import does so only for side effects, and doesn't expose it to the environment (unless it adds itself to the global object). Also, `gitgraph.js` makes no sense as an import name, unless that's the name of the package you're importing, if you import a file, you want to give a relative path to it.

Comment: @jaredgorski I tryit, but I got more errors. `TypeError: gitgraph_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a is not a constructor`

Answer (score 0):

In React projects (and actually in all modern JavaScript projects), you split your code across multiple JavaScript
files - so-called modules. You do this, to keep each file/ module focused and manageable.

To still access functionality in another file, you need `export` (to make it available) and `import` (to get access) statements.

You got two different types of
exports: `default` (unnamed) and `named` exports:

```
 default => export default ...;
 named => export const someData = ...;
```

example#01:

```
#Person.js 
const person = { name: "firstName" }'
export default person;
```

Now you should use `import Person from 'Person'`

example#02:

```
#clean.js
 export const clean = () => ...}
```

then you should use `import { clean } from 'clean'`

---

default export:

```
import person from './person';
import prs from './person';
```

named export:

```
import { smth } from './utility';
import { smth as Smth } from './utility';
import * as bundled from './utility';
```

Comment: If you understand this concept then its easy for you to go and check the sources of the import you wanted to import in your file.. that can be `named` or `default` import.

Comment: @AlexisSanchez, lets say you run a command "npm i gulp --save", which installs gulp... Now, go to its github source or find it in your node_modules folder and check the index.js or related root js file.. mostly it will be a default export and sometimes named..